# I am getting a missing positional argument error.(linked list in python)

Tags: python, data-structures, singly-linked-list

code:

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None

def printlist(self):
    temp=self.head
    while(temp):
        print(temp.data,end=" ")
        temp=temp.next

def insert_at_start(self,new_data):
    new_node=node(new_data)
    if self.head==None:
        new_node=self.head
    else:
        new_node.next=self.head
        self.head=new_node

l1=linkedlist()
insert_at_start(1)
insert_at_start(5)
insert_at_start(1)
insert_at_start(7)
insert_at_start(5)

l1.printlist()
```

error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linkedlist.py", line 65, in 
    insert_at_start(1)
TypeError: insert_at_start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'new_data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have the indentation problem that those 2 functions (`printlist` and `insert_at_start`)  should be methods, so indent them to lie in the `linkedlist` class. Also two more errors: one is, you need the call

```
l1.insert_at_start(..)
```

i.e. the method call on the instance. And the other is a logical error that resides in the lines of:

```
if self.head == None:
    new_node = self.head
```

When `.head` does not exist yet, don't you think `.head` should be the one assigned to the `new_node`?

Also note that `l1` is probably one of the most confusing variable names ever existed, please change it; and *PascalCase* your class names.

Answer (score 1):

You have an indentation problem: `insert_at_start` is not a method of `linkedlist` class because it is defined outside of the class scope and that's why it requires 2 args.

Try this instead:

```
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None

    def printlist(self):
        temp=self.head
        while(temp):
            print(temp.data,end=" ")
            temp=temp.next

    def insert_at_start(self,new_data):
        new_node=node(new_data)
        if self.head==None:
            new_node=self.head
        else:
            new_node.next=self.head
            self.head=new_node

l1=linkedlist()
l1.insert_at_start(1)
l1.insert_at_start(5)
l1.insert_at_start(1)
l1.insert_at_start(7)
l1.insert_at_start(5)
l1.printlist()
```